# epstopdf pdfminorversion=7 error

Tags: beamer, epstopdf

When using pdfminorversion=5 I get a warning which I wanted to get rid of (found PDF version 1.7, but at most version 1.5 allowed). Some googling gave me the "solution" `pdfminorversion=7`. However, now it doesn't work at all anymore, since it gives me the error:
PDF version cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file. `<to be read again>` \edef

I think you can use any .eps file.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{epstopdf}    
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
   \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,angle=90]{test.eps}
   \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it would help if you would mention which warning you got and what "now it doesn't work at all" actually means. Don't forget that we don't have your eps and so can't test your example.

Comment: I think you can use any eps file.

Comment: Do you think or did you try? There are example eps in the the mwe package, e.g. example-image.eps.

Comment: How do I use the example-image.eps file after adding the package ``mwe``? I can not just write the file name, since there is no file.

Comment: The point however is more, if you use your own .eps and the package epstopdf to convert that .eps to pdf which is then used as a graphic.

Comment: @Diger no you would have to generate a PDF 1.7 EPS file. You can just write the name try `\includegraphics{example-image}` (you do not need to load the mwe package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

```
 ! pdfTeX error (setup): PDF version cannot be changed after data is written to 
 the PDF file.
```

This means that your command to change the pdf version is too late. Move it before the \documentclass command.

Beside this `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7` is obsolete. The correct command to set the minor version is `\pdfminorversion=7`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this new or specific to Beamer Class? I've used this command before in a report and I had it right after the command ``\usepackage{epstopdf}``?

Comment: the error is not new, you always get it if some code has written to the pdf. In this case it is something in beamer which opens the pdf, but it could happen also with some other package. Set the pdf version always as early as possible.